# Get list of all files by mask in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, find, file-search

I want to find all `*.h`,`*.cpp` files in folders with defined mask, like `*/trunk/src*`. So, I can find separately `*.h` and `*.cpp` files:

```
find . -path "*/trunk/src/*.h"
find . -path "*/trunk/src/*.cpp"
```

What is the best way to get the file-list both of types (`*.h` and `*.cpp`)?

PS I'd like to pipe the list to `grep`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `-o` for "or":

```
find . -path '*/trunk/src/*.h' -o -path '*/trunk/src/*.cpp'
```

which is the same as

```
find . -path '*/trunk/src/*' \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \)
```

If you want to run grep on these files:

```
find . \( -path '*/trunk/src/*.h' -o -path '*/trunk/src/*.cpp' \) -exec grep PATTERN {} +
```

or

```
find . -path '*/trunk/src/*' \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec grep PATTERN {} +
```

Answer (score 4):

In bash, turn on the [globstar](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) option so that `**` matches any level of subdirectories. You can do this from your `~/.bashrc`. Also turn on the `extglob` options to activate ksh extended patterns.

```
shopt -s globstar extglob
```

Then:

```
grep PATTERN **/trunk/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

Beware that bash versions up to 4.2 follow symlinks to directories when you use `**`.

Zsh makes this easier, you don't need to set any options and can just type

```
grep PATTERN **/trunk/src/**/*.(h|cpp)
```

If the command line is too long, and you're on Linux or other platform with GNU grep, you can make `grep` recurse instead of the shell to save on the command line length.

```
grep -R --include='*.cpp' --include='*.h' PATTERN **/trunk/src
```